# How to copy a file using a new name while keeping part of the old name?

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have 12 Files in a folder each names a_01.jpg a_02.jpg (...) etc

I want to copy those files in the same folder using a new name like e.g. daniela_01.jpg etc

So I tried using a batchfile with:

```
    copy C:\Users\name\temp\a_*.jpg C:\Users\name\temp\daniela_*.jpg
```

this didn't work out as well as

```
    copy C:\Users\name\temp\a_??.jpg C:\Users\name\temp\daniela_??.jpg
```

I dont get the 12 Files... It only copys one single piece...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "oldpfx=a_"
SET "newpfx=daniela_"
SET "delimchar=_"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=%delimchar%" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%oldpfx%*.jpg" '
 ) DO (
  ECHO COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a%delimchar%%%b" "%sourcedir%\%newpfx%%%b" 
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

You'd also need to specify your old and new prefixes. It would be possible to calculate `delimchar` by using

```
set "delimchar=%oldpfx:~-1%"
```

but the delimiter can be only one character, not a string.

Note that since your old prefix is the same as the end of the new, re-running the procedure would attempt to do the copy again *and* would try to copy `daniela_*.jpg` to `daniela_daniela_*.jpg`.

---

Best to tell us the entire problem from the get-go.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "namesfile=U:\q25053916.txt"
SET "oldpfx=a"
SET "delimchar=_"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=%delimchar%" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%oldpfx%%delimchar%*.jpg" '
 ) DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%p IN ('type "%namesfile%"') DO (
   ECHO COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a%delimchar%%%b" "%destdir%\%%p%delimchar%%%b" 
  )
)


GOTO :EOF
```

By preference, make the source and destination different. That way, the process can be re-run easily.

All you need to do above changing the variables is to set up your names in a simple textfile (I used a file named `q25053916.txt` containing your data for my testing.)

`q25053916.txt`

```
daniela
maximilian
Fabian
etc
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Well it would be the easiest if the solution could keep the rest... so it only changes the a_ keeping the 01.jpg etc from the source... Is this possible? I have to run the script 50 times with different names ^^ so.. daniela, maximilian etc ... Sorry for my silly questions.. Its my first time with powershell ^^

Comment: "it quite doesnt work" - er, do you really expect us to enter a guessing game about what "quite doesn't work?"

Comment: Well it runs the copy command, but there are no files in the directory afterwards.. (added a pause to see the commands) the prefixes and all would be perfectly fine.. but no jpegs in the folder. the command looks like this: COPY "C:\Users\Username\temp\source\a_12.jpg" "C:\Users\Username\temp\lena_12.jpg"

Comment: You'd need to remove the `echo` keyword before the `copy`. It's there to show you what the script proposes to do so that if there is an error, no damage occurs. Remove it and the `copy` will be executed. You may also want to add `>nul` at the end of the `copy` line. This will suppress the `1 file(s) copied` message.

Comment: Thank you a lot Magoo! Works perfectly! Learned a lot for my tech education from this! :) Thank you for explaining! :)

Answer (score 1):

let say your files are on the c:\temp dir :

```
ls c:\temp\*.jpg | %{ copy $_.fullname c:\temp\daniel$($_.name)}
```

update after your comment (remove the 1st letter)

```
ls c:\temp\*.jpg | %{copy $_.fullname c:\temp\daniel$(($_.name).substring(1))}
```

in batch you could do :

```
copy *.jpg daniel*.jpg
```

Comment: Your batch solution doesnt work because I only have to change the part before the "_" with the ls thing there is no error.. the window pops up and immediately closes..

Comment: open a powershell console then write the command, you will see if there is an error

Comment: It works now.. Kinda.. But it keeps the a from a_01.jpg... so daniel gets daniela...

Comment: hm yes, but the a shall be replaced with for example daniel... so this would be PERFECT if the a gets replaced ^^

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression:

```
ls C:\Users\name\temp\a_*.jpg | % {
    if ($_ -match 'a_(.*?).jpg') {
        Copy-Item $_ ('C:\Users\name\temp\daniela_' + $Matches[1] + '.jpg')
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens... Powershellwindow pops up and closes =/ there is an error saying that there is no positioning parameter (had to translate this from german.. hope this is the right name for it ;D)

Comment: @Fabian, I've fixed the example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
Get-Item 'C:\source\folder\a_*.jpg' | % {
  $target = Join-Path 'C:\target\folder' ($_.Name -replace 'a_','daniela_')
  Copy-Item $_ $target
}
```